# Set form captions runtime

Tags: acumatica

I can set the captions for fields or actions at run-time. But how do you do that on form or dialog ? Such controls aren't exactly accessible inside the customization.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

Form captions aren't commonly displayed so I customized the Cases screen to show them:
[image]

Form control can't be manipulated from BQL because it isn't bound to a DAC field (it's bound to a DataView). That leaves JavaScript as the only option as far as I know. This doesn't follow best practice but you can change the caption using JS once you found out the control ID using the browser Inspect Element feature:
[image]

Control ID in this case is 'ctl00_phF_form_header' and the last child of that control is the caption text. With JavaScript you can replace that Caption Text control:

```
document.getElementById("ctl00_phF_form_header").removeChild(document.getElementById("ctl00_phF_form_header").lastChild);
document.getElementById("ctl00_phF_form_header").appendChild(document.createTextNode('Test Caption'));
```

[image]